# Gmail add-on define pattern for the urlFetchWhitelist

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm creating a Gmail add-on and one of the use cases is that user could define a server URL from which the data should be fetched. However, the URL always will have trailing part in the domain name

> https:// *[part which user defines]* .my.domain.com

Currently, there is no option to deploy Gmail add-on without providing the urlFetchWhitelist list. In my case, I can specify the end part of the whitelisted URLs, whereas the [GAS gives only define prefix](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#whitelisting_urls)

Are there any approaches how to define some pattern for the urlFetchWhitelist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single [wildcard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/allowlist-url#using_wildcards) character (*) to match a subdomain.