# Wildcard in the URLFetch whitelist

Tags: gmail-addons

In the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish#technical_requirements) is said

> If your add-on functionality demands it, you can use a * character as
>   wildcard in the whitelist.

I have tried multiple ways to define it with no luck. Could somebody show a simple example how it can be done?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407688/gmail-add-on-define-pattern-for-the-urlfetchwhitelist) to a problem I have related to this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards.

You need a complete domain or don't use Whitelist at all (is not recommended).

This part of documentation explains:

[Whitelisting URLs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests#whitelisting_urls)

The prefixes you add to the manifest must satisfy the following requirements:

**Each prefix must have a full domain.**

Comment: Thanks, It seems like the documentation got updated. Previously, the following statement "If your add-on functionality demands it, you can use a * character as wildcard in the whitelist." was present for both urlFetchWhitelist and openLinkUrlPrefixes in this doc https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish Currently, you can apply the wildcard only for openLinkUrlPrefixes like this "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [ "*"